# div in table cell longer than parent

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want three divs in a table cell in one row and the last one abbreviated if it doesn't fit:
https://jsfiddle.net/prwrjy6r/1/

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="tablecell">
    <div id="asd">
      test
    </div>
    <div id="qwe">
      1234123
    </div>
    <div id="yxc">
      long text this is
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```
#asd {
  width: 4em;
  display: table-cell;
}
#qwe {
  width: 4em;
  display: table-cell;
}
#yxc {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#tablecell {
  width: 10em;
  border: solid;
}
```

The size of the table cell should be 50%, but when I try this, the last div expand the size of the whole cell.

Comment: is this what you wanted https://jsfiddle.net/prwrjy6r/5/

Comment: no, but PenAndPapers solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```css
.asd {
  width: 3em;
  float: left;
}

.qwe {
  width: 5em;
  float: left;
}

.yxc {
  width: 2em;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#tablecell {
  width: 10em;
  border: solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#tablecell:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="tablecell">
      <div class="asd">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="qwe">
        1234123
      </div>
      <div class="yxc">
        long text this is hellow
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I want. Could you explain it to me? Why do I need the after pseudoelement?

Comment: I used that after pseudo class to clear its float of its children. try to check this link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/